# Value on button as in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal of tracking shipment, in which I want to have values on button which are entered in textbox.

I have tried but it didn't work.

Please help me to sort out the error.

```html
<script>
 window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('cno').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    document.getElementById('cnor').value = this.value;
})};
</script>
<div class="modal fade" id="track"   tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
           aria-labelledby="trackLabel" aria-hidden="true">

             <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
               <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="trackLabel">Track Your Shipment.</h3>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-body">
              <form id="Track">
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Enter Consignment Number</label>
                    <input id="cno" name="cno" type="text" class="form-control"  required="" placeholder="Eg.:- JU05GHY1532" onkeyup="function()"><button type="submit" id="cnor" name="cnor" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Track</button>
                </div>
               </div>
               
             </form>
                 </div>
               </div><!--/.modal-content-->
             </div><!--/.modal-dialog-->
          </div><!-- Modal END -->
```

Comment: add code at the end of code

Comment: 1 error is in your javascript, don't use dot (.) in ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until your elements are loading so move code to `window.onload` callback or add the code after the element in your markup.

If you want to update the text content shown in the button then update [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property and use [Html5 `input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event for synchronous update.

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('cno.').addEventListener('input', function() {
    document.getElementById('cno.r').textContent = this.value;
  });
}
```

```html
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('cno.').addEventListener('input', function() {
      document.getElementById('cno.r').textContent = this.value;
    });
  }
</script>
<div class="modal fade" id="track" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="trackLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="trackLabel">Track Your Shipment.</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="Track">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Enter Consignment Number</label>
                <input id="cno." name="cno." type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Eg.:- JU05GHY1532"><button type="submit" id="cno.r" name="cno.r" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Track</button>
              </div>
            </div>

        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="track" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="trackLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="trackLabel">Track Your Shipment.</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="Track">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Enter Consignment Number</label>
                <input id="cno." name="cno." type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Eg.:- JU05GHY1532"><button type="submit" id="cno.r" name="cno.r" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Track</button>
              </div>
            </div>

        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('cno.').addEventListener('input', function() {
      document.getElementById('cno.r').textContent = this.value;
    });
  </script>
```

---

**FYI :** It's not best practice to use `.` in the [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) value better to keep it as a valid identifier.

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) :

> Note: Using characters except ASCII letters and digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.

Comment: Sir exactly I want that if user type in textbox it should display in button at same time as well

Comment: @BabaluPandey :  for that update `textContent` property and `input` event

Comment: @BabaluPandey : check the snippet added

Comment: First or second??

Comment: Got, but Track word is removed

Comment: @BabaluPandey : do you want to append with that ??

Comment: @BabaluPandey : glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

```
$("#input").on('change', function(){
   $("#button").val($("#input").val());
});
```

Comment: I have posted it as a separate answer . @Babalu Pandey

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"/>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="input" />
  <button id="continue">Continue</button>
</body>
```

---

**Modal HTML:**

```
<button id="track">Track Button</button>
```

**jQuery:** (Triggers on change in input field)

```
$("#input").on('change', function(){
   $("#track").val($("#input").val());
});
```

OR

**jQuery:** (Triggers on button click)

```
$("#continue").on('click', function(){
   $("#track").val($("#input").val());
});
```